# Netbeans annotation error

Tags: netbeans, openide

NetBeans do not accept my code. Why? [See the pic.](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8c368f673e.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the code from

```
package org.demo.myfilter;

import org.demo.textfilter.TextFilter;

@ServiceProvider(service=TextFilter.class)
public class UpperCaseFilter implements TextFilter {

    public String process(String s) {
        return s.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

into

```
package org.demo.myfilter;

import org.demo.textfilter.TextFilter;
import org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider;

@ServiceProvider(service=TextFilter.class)
public class UpperCaseFilter implements TextFilter {

    public String process(String s) {
        return s.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

Note: You can leverage the Fix Imports item from the Source menu (CTRL-SHIFT-I/Clover-SHIFT-I) to take care of the second one automatically, if you have declared the dependeny between your module and the NetBeans platform Utilities API module

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the annotations you're using.

E.g, import org.whatever.package.contains.ServiceProvider;

Answer (score 1):

```
import {package}.ServiceProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing an import. Can you import "ServiceProvider"? It's hard to know for sure without know more about your project setup, but that's my first guess.